# Collimating a UV LED

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, fiber-optics, light-emitting-diodes

I have a task of narrowing a UV LED (375 to 400nm) of diameter 5mm to 1mm on the surface of an object. The LED has a peak output power of 2.2mw (quite low). It has an half Intensity angle of 10 degrees. Is there a simple setup using micro lens or a collimating device to complete this?

I'm not worried about how much power does it have on the surface. My primary goal is to narrow the beam diameter from 5mm to 1mm.

Comment: 5mm is the size of the LED surface?

Comment: just by conservation of etendue (=light throughput. ~solid angle of divergence * area), since you have light cones of 10 degrees emanating from 5 mm diameter surface, to squeeze that into 1 mm diameter, you will need a high numerical aperture lens that can give you light cones of 50 degrees. You can buy relatively cheap condenser lenses on Thorlabs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can arrange lenses as a beam compressor (or expander if you reverse the order of the lenses) for a columnated input beam. The main idea is that you use the first lens to collimate the expanding beam, the second lens focuses to a point, the third lens is placed so that it’s focal point re-collimates the beam when it has the required width.

Strictly speaking, the first lens might not be needed but will make it easier to work with.

If you want an expanded beam, swap the order of the last two lenses and reposition them to collimate the expanded beam.

[image]